# Getting a Unique Constraint Violated Error but I haven't used a unique constraint in Oracle SQL?

Tags: oracle, constraints, unique

I keep getting this error message:

ORA-00001: unique constraint (SQL_HZWNCULHFYLOUVQBOPQMRYNLQ.SYS_C0062427812) violated ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

Its because the code in the musicID column is repeated. However, I haven't put any unique constraints on this column so why is this happening?

basically, in the music download table, the patel11 insert command is the line that gets the error and so the resultant table doesn't include this line. I can't seem to understand why though?

I've included the code for the music download table first bc that's where my issue is but then as an edit underneath I've included the full code so far in case my issue is elsewhere in the code.

````
CREATE TABLE music_download_table
    (
        userID  VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        musicID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        downloadDate DATE NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_usertable FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES user_table(userID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_musictable FOREIGN KEY(musicID) REFERENCES music_table(musicID)
    );
--check music download table
DESC music_download_table;
--insert rows into music download table
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('kendj3', 'M002', '03-May-18');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('johnsj9', 'M005', '01-May-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('patel11', 'M002', '06-May-18');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('johnsj9', 'M001', '06-May-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('kendj3', 'M003', '01-Aug-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('keita77', 'M004', '02-Aug-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('Simpb91', 'M007', '05-Sep-18');
--show table
SELECT * FROM music_download_table;```


--below is the full code for this so far if that helps anyone figure it out?

``--create user table
CREATE TABLE user_table
    (
        userID  VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY, 
        names VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL, 
        emailAddress VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
    );
--check table
DESC user_table
--insert rows into user table
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('kendj3', 'Kenderine, J', 'kendj3@hotmail.co.uk');
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('patel11', 'Patel, F', 'patel11@ntl.co.uk');
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('flak05', 'Flavel, K', 'flak05@freeserve.co.uk');
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('johnsj9', 'Johnson, J', 'johnsj9@msn.co.uk');
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('keita77', 'Keita, R', 'keita77@hotmail.co.uk');
INSERT INTO user_table VALUES('Simpb91', 'Simpson, B', 'Simpb91@tesco.co.uk');
--show user table
SELECT * FROM user_table;
--create category table
CREATE TABLE category_table
    (
        categoryCode VARCHAR2(4) PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR2(20) NOT NULL
    );
--check table
DESC category_table;
--create music table
CREATE TABLE music_table
    (
        musicID VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR2(40) NOT NULL,
        categoryCode VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
        costPerDownload NUMBER(4,2) CHECK(costPerDownload > 0),
        CONSTRAINT fk_categorytable FOREIGN KEY(categoryCode) REFERENCES category_table(categoryCode)
    );
--check table
DESC music_table;
--insert rows into music table
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M001', 'James Bond: Golden Eyes', 'C13', '0.99');
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M002', 'Lake House', 'C13', '1.99');
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M003', 'Dvorak: Symphony No 9', 'C11', '1.49');
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M004', 'Handel:Water Music', 'C11', '1.79');
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M005', 'Sense and Sensibility', 'C13', '1.50');
INSERT INTO music_table VALUES('M006', 'Beatles:Yesterday', 'C12', '1.10');
INSERT INTO music_table Values('M007', 'Elton John: Your Song', 'C12', '0.89');
--show music table
SELECT * FROM music_table;
--create music download table
CREATE TABLE music_download_table
    (
        userID  VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        musicID VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
        downloadDate DATE NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT fk_usertable FOREIGN KEY(userID) REFERENCES user_table(userID),
        CONSTRAINT fk_musictable FOREIGN KEY(musicID) REFERENCES music_table(musicID)
    );
--check music download table
DESC music_download_table;
--insert rows into music download table
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('kendj3', 'M002', '03-May-18');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('johnsj9', 'M005', '01-May-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('patel11', 'M002', '06-May-18');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('johnsj9', 'M001', '06-May-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('kendj3', 'M003', '01-Aug-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('keita77', 'M004', '02-Aug-19');
INSERT INTO music_download_table VALUES('Simpb91', 'M007', '05-Sep-18');
--show table
SELECT * FROM music_download_table;
--insert rows into category table
INSERT INTO category_table VALUES('C11', 'Classic');
INSERT INTO category_table VALUES('C12', 'Pop-Rock');
INSERT INTO category_table VALUES('C13', 'Movie Soundtrack');
--show category table ```
````

Comment: Are you sure a unique constraint wasn't added after the table was created? Or a trigger that's inserting somewhere else with a unique constraint?

Comment: I deleted the table and then recreated it using this code again and I still got the error. The foreign key musicID comes from another table and musicID is the primary key in that table and so has unique constraints - does that matter?

Comment: also, what is a trigger?

Comment: the error seems to be for the third insert line if that helps anyone figure it out?

Comment: The extended version [also seems OK](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3c9b078e1f0725bbc8ca3ddbd95033a). You need to start by looking at `user_constraints`, `all_constraints` or `dba_constraints` to see what `SYS_C0062427812` is - which schema and table it's against, as it doesn't seem to be this one. Could you maybe have a synonym to the same table name in a different schema?

Comment: Do you have a primary constraint in the table  on whose INSERT you are getting the error message ?

Comment: What is `SQL_HZWNCULHFYLOUVQBOPQMRYNLQ`? It's a schema name (and the unique constraint that is violated is on a table in that schema). That's a pretty odd name for a schema (user), do you know what it is? In any case, `select * from all_cons_columns where owner = 'SQL_HZWNCULHFYLOUVQBOPQMRYNLQ' and constraint_name = 'SYS_C0062427812'` will tell you on what table and on which columns that constraint is. Run the same selecting `from all_constraints` to see who generated the constraint, when it was last changed, etc.

Comment: What tool / environment are you running this against ? The DBMS_SQL suggest there's some (web ui ?) layer in between you and the database that might be broken.

Comment: That looks like you are using LiveSQL based on the schema name.  We need to see your entire script so that we can run it LIveSQL as well